# TaskStackBuilder - backwards compatible or not?

Tags: android, stack

I'm setting up a notification following the example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). My app is compatible with API 15 and ulterior versions. This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // send notification

        // API < 16 so have to use compat
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                //.setSmallIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(icon_id_here))
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, UpcomingTest.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(UpcomingTest.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

When reading the information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) about TaskStackBuilder, it says "TaskStackBuilder provides a backward-compatible way to obey the correct conventions around cross-task navigation on the device's version of the platform.". However I'm getting an error that says that I need to target minimum API 16 in order to use TaskStackBuilder. Is there anything else I need to do to actually make it backward-compatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be importing [android.app.TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) rather than [android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) - check your imports.

Comment: Gorgeous. I was close to wrap the call with an `if (VERSION.SDK_INT...)`